# Changing selected option on button click

Tags: jquery, button, jquery-mobile

On click of a button I'm wanting to change the selected option in a select list to correspond to the button that was clicked.
This is what I have so far,  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesil/8RUBj)

```
$('#btnCityAuckland').click(function(){
    $('#City').val('A');
})
```

I do have some jQuery there, but its probably miles off being right as it cant be that simple.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
$('#btnAuckland').click(function(){ 
    $('#City').val('A').trigger('change');
})​
```

Apparently you can just call the `.trigger()` method after setting the value.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8RUBj/11/

**EDIT**
Also, it's better if you use `data` attributes to set the value, and classes, and then you can do all your buttons in one go.

```
$('.select-change').click(function(){ 
    $('#City').val($(this).data('val')).trigger('change');
})​
```

Demo v2: http://jsfiddle.net/8RUBj/15/

Comment: Exactly what I was after. Haven't seen .trigger() used before. I learnt something new :)  Thanks heaps!

Answer (score 3):

Your code is right, just that you mistyped `$('#btnCityAuckland')` , it really is:

```
$('#btnAuckland')
```

Working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6XEG9/)

You could also automate selecting the option based on the button clicked, instead of hardcoding the ID's, like so:

```
$('div > a').click(function(){ //click handler for all city buttons
    $("#City option:contains('"+$(this).text()+"')").attr("selected",true);
    $("#City").selectmenu('refresh', true); //Refresh to show name on select
})​
```

Working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5CgUZ/1/)

Comment: yes the value changes, but it's not a visible change. (the select isn't updated and needs to be triggered manually. Thanks jQuery Mobile.)

Comment: Thanks Nelson, And fully agree ahren.

Comment: @Jamesil I've added the refresh call necessary so the select picks the change. You can see it in my last code, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you weren't using jQuery Mobile your code would work as is. With jQuery Mobile you can make the pseudo-select refresh by calling `.selectmenu("refresh")` on it as follows:

```
$('div[data-role="controlgroup"] a').click(function(){
      $('#City').val( $(this).text().charAt(0) ).selectmenu("refresh");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8RUBj/18/

Note that you don't need to assign a separate click handler for each button: for demonstration purposes I've shown a rather clunky way of making the code more generic such that it will work without changing your html, but you could add `data-` attributes or something to the buttons to indicate what value is associated with each.

[More information about jQuery Mobile select methods](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/selects/methods.html).

Comment: +1 - didn't notice the correlation between the first char and the select value!

Comment: Thanks @ahren. Obviously the first-letter thing wouldn't work if there were additional cities starting with the same letter since they'd have to have different values in the select, but like I said above that was just a demonstration of one way to make the code more generic...